# Unix script appends ^M at end of each line

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have a Unix shell script which does the following:

1. creates a backup of a file
2. appends some text to a file

Now in #2 if I insert a text, ^M gets appended on all the lines of the file.

For example:

```
echo " a" >> /cust/vivek.txt
echo " b" >> /cust/vivek.txt

vi vivek.txt
abc^M
bcd^M
a^M
b^M
```

Any way to avoid this?

Comment: show us how the text is appended to file by the script

Comment: Did you create this file on Windows machine and then transferred it on unix/linux machine? End of line is interpreted differently in MS-DOS and Linux/Unix environments. On MS-DOS, end of line is indicated by new line character and carriage return, whereas on Unix, new line feed indicates end of line. This causes ^M characters, if you're not careful about the transfer mode between MS-DOS and Unix/Linux

Comment: i have copied the base file from windows machine only, now any way to resolve this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I'm not sure how `echo` could be producing `^M` characters but you can remove them by running `dos2unix` on your file, like this:

```
dos2unix /cust/vivek.txt
```

Comment: Never knew about dos2unix, worked like a charm for me! Cheers

Comment: `echo -e "\r" ` produces such

Answer (score 7):

Only

```
sed -e "s/\r//g" file
```

worked for me

Answer (score 6):

`^M` is a carriage return, and is commonly seen when files are copied from Windows.  Use:

```
od -xc filename
```

that should give a low-level list of what your file looks like.  If you file does not come from Windows then another possibility is that your terminal setting are not translating correctly.  Check that the TERM environment variable is correct.

If the file has come from Windows, then use `dos2unix` or `sed 's/\r//' file > file.new`

Answer (score 3):

I suspect this may be an artifact of your vi settings, rather than the concatenation.

What does

```
cat -v -e filename
```

show ? This command will dump out your file and mark the control characters so it's clear what's *really* in your file. See also [this Superuser question/answer set](https://superuser.com/questions/39313/bash-script-appending-m-to-filename).

Comment: -v = use ^ and M- notation, except for LFD and TAB;
-E = display $ at end of each line;
-e = equivalent to -vE;

So -v -e = -v -vE;

Redundant?
Shouldn't we use just "-e" instead of "-v -e"?

Answer (score 3):

If you are using windows, you can use notepad++ and to try Edit > EOL Conversion > Unix/OSX Format, before load file to server.

Answer (score 2):

^M are the meta characters which entered your file when it was used in windows.

the dos2unix command can fix this.

```
dos2unix <filename>
```