# Flask bad interpreter

Tags: python, bash, flask, shebang

Following this tutorial: http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-iv-database I've reached the part where I'm supposed to create my first db and migrate it's tables.

Having `db_create.py`, in the root directory of my xyzTest app, with the following contents:

```
#!flask/bin/python
from migrate.versioning import api
from config import SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI
from config import SQLALCHEMY_MIGRATE_REPO
from app import db
import os.path
db.create_all()
if not os.path.exists(SQLALCHEMY_MIGRATE_REPO):
    api.create(SQLALCHEMY_MIGRATE_REPO, 'database repository')
    api.version_control(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI, SQLALCHEMY_MIGRATE_REPO)
else:
    api.version_control(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI, SQLALCHEMY_MIGRATE_REPO,
                        api.version(SQLALCHEMY_MIGRATE_REPO))
```

Whether I execute script with the virtualenv active (`virtualenv flask; source flask/bin/activate`), or not, the results of the execution of the script is identical.

`./db_create.py` returns:

> -bash: ./db_create.py: flask/bin/python^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

`python db_create.py` returns:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "db_create.py", line 2, in 
>       from migrate.versioning import api
>   ImportError: No module named 'migrate'

Yet, both `flask-sqlalchemy` and `sqlalchemy-migrate` are installed, along with the flask framework its self.

`ppip list`

```
argparse (1.2.1)
Babel (1.3)
blinker (1.3)
coverage (3.7.1)
decorator (3.4.2)
Flask (0.10.1)
Flask-Babel (0.9)
Flask-Login (0.2.11)
Flask-Mail (0.9.1)
Flask-OpenID (1.2.4)
Flask-SQLAlchemy (2.0)
Flask-WhooshAlchemy (0.56)
Flask-WTF (0.11)
flipflop (1.0)
guess-language (0.2)
itsdangerous (0.24)
Jinja2 (2.7.3)
MarkupSafe (0.23)
pbr (0.11.0)
pip (1.5.6)
python-openid (2.2.5)
pytz (2015.4)
setuptools (5.5.1)
six (1.9.0)
speaklater (1.3)
SQLAlchemy (0.9.9)
sqlalchemy-migrate (0.9.6)
sqlparse (0.1.15)
Tempita (0.5.2)
Werkzeug (0.10.4)
Whoosh (2.7.0)
wsgiref (0.1.2)
WTForms (2.0.2)
```

Comment: you should print the directory that it's trying to go to, and then see if you can cd to that directory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Searching to find the meaning of `^M`, I encountered this article [Unix script appends ^M at end of each line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15020883/unix-script-appends-m-at-end-of-each-line)

I have applied same solution as the selected answer, `dos2unix db_create.py` and fixed it.

It happened because I'm writing from a windows machine, into a folder linux folder. I executed the following command: `find ./ -name "*.py" -not -path "./flask/*" -exec dos2unix {} \;` to ensure that I won't have same issue with any other file.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a problem with the sqlalchemy-migrate version. The tutorial is utilizing sqlalchemy-migrate v.07.2 (see the comments section of the tutorial link you posted in the question).  Also the version of sqlalchemy in the tutorial is older (from the author "You should be using sqlalchemy 0.7.9 with sqlalchemy-migrate. That project was not updated to work with sqlalchemy 0.8.")